# Creating new headings

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I am writing an assignment for school in the *memoir*-class. However, I need to use deeper headings than standard LaTeX would allow (even though people say it is not typographically advisable to do so). So I would like to create new headings just like the ones that already exist (thus headings that also work with hyperref, indented appearance in TOC etc.), albeit of a deeper level.

For a previous assignment (one I made with the *book*-class) I tried to copy the definitions of \subsection I found in *book.cls* mutatis mutandis to a new .sty-file. I used (with *headingnivV* as the name of the new sectioning command):

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter {headingnivV}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\theheadingnivV{\@Alph\c@headingnivV}

\newcommand\headingnivV{\@startsection{headingnivV}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\newcommand*\l@headingnivV{\@dottedtocline{4}{11.1em}{2.3em}}

  \def\toclevel@headingnivV{4}
  \def\l@headingnivV{\@dottedtocline{4}{11.1em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
```

This did the job, but it printed the text twice: one time as intended, with the mark-up as defined, and one time as ordinary text. I attached a screenshot below (I used `\headingnivV{Here comes my heading`}). I couldn't find the exact problem. This bug wasn't a real problem for the previous assignment but it will be for the new one.

[image: screenshot of text printed twice]

Could someone please explain how I can make additional headings in a *memoir* document, in all aspects equal to the already existing ones except their 'level'? I have no real experience with plain TeX (some with LaTeX) so I would be happy to see how this would be done. If possible I would like to do this without using any packages for I need to style the headings as defined in a style guide we have to use (except if a package would make this a lot easier) and I would like to minimise the probability of package clashes. I think I will have to make at least 3-4 extra levels of headings, possibly more.

I use *xelatex* but it would be nice of it would also compile with *latex* (as I have to hand it in in a .docx-format).

This is an MWE:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
  \newcounter {headingnivV}[subsubsection]
  \renewcommand\theheadingnivV{\@Alph\c@headingnivV}
  \newcommand\headingnivV{\@startsection{headingnivV}{4}{\z@}%
                                       {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                       {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
  \newcommand*\l@headingnivV{\@dottedtocline{4}{11.1em}{2.3em}}
    \def\toclevel@headingnivV{4}
    \def\l@headingnivV{\@dottedtocline{4}{11.1em}{2.3em}}
  \makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{9}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{9}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Test 1}
\chapter{Test 2}
\section{Test 3}
\subsection{Test 4}
\subsubsection{Test 5}
\headingnivV{Test 6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  **Edit:** I took the liberty to edit your question to remove the final thanks, as the style of this site dictates. :-)

Comment: book already declares two levels of heading below subsubsection (levels 4 and 5 ) so it isn't clear this is needed at all

Comment: What I can tell you, for now, is that you are getting the duplicate title because you are forgetting that, in your setup, you also need to say `\let\headingnivVmark\@gobble`.  (Interesting puzzle, it took me half an hour to spot it, although, in retrospect, it was rather obvious… ;-)

Comment: BTW, the line that says `\def\l@headingnivV{\@dottedtocline{4}{11.1em}{2.3em}}` is a duplicate if the preceding `\newcommand*\l@headingnivV{...}`: delete it.

Comment: Thank you, adding the *\let…* solves the duplicate printing of the text and thus making the commands usable for this assignment. This is necessary because I need more levels than just \paragraph and \subparagraph. Because I needed more levels anyway, it seemed easier to just make an alternate to \(sub)paragraph than to try to alter those 2 commands as well.